Why did the redis distributed lock fail？
We have a system that deploys 16 pod and uses @ Scheduled stand-alone tasks plus redis locks to avoid concurrent execution, but now we find that the redis lock has failed and several pod have got the lock. Here is the code：
private static final long TRY_LOCK_TIME_OUT = 50L;
private static final long LOCK_TIME_OUT = 600000L;

@Scheduled(cron = "0 */5 * * * ?", zone = "Asia/Shanghai")
public void retryNotice() {
        //加锁
        String requestId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        String lockKey = "btb::bos::notice::retry::lock";
        try {
            boolean lockSuccess = distributeLock.tryLock(lockKey, requestId, TRY_LOCK_TIME_OUT, LOCK_TIME_OUT);
            if (!lockSuccess) {
                //加锁失败，丢弃不处理
                return;
            }
            LOGGER.info("NoticeRetryJob execute start");
            noticeErrorService.retry();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("NoticeRetryJob execute error", e);
        } finally {
            //解锁
            distributeLock.unLock(lockKey, requestId);
        }
    }


private static final String LUA_LOCK = "return redis.call('SET',KEYS[1],ARGV[1],'NX','PX',ARGV[2])";
private static final String LUA_UNLOCK = "if redis.call('get',KEYS[1]) == ARGV[1] then return redis.call('del',KEYS[1]) else return 0 end";

private static final DefaultRedisScript<String> LUA_SCRIPT_LOCK = new DefaultRedisScript<>(LUA_LOCK, String.class);
private static final DefaultRedisScript<Long> LUA_SCRIPT_UNLOCK = new DefaultRedisScript<>(LUA_UNLOCK, Long.class);

private static final int SLEEP_TIME = 50;

public boolean tryLock(String key, String requestId, long tryLockTimeOut, long timeOut) {
        long timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
        while (tryLockTimeOut == 0 || System.currentTimeMillis() - timestamp < tryLockTimeOut) {
            String result = c8sClusterStringRedisClient.execute(
                    LUA_SCRIPT_LOCK, Collections.singletonList(key), requestId, String.valueOf(timeOut));
            if ("OK".equalsIgnoreCase(result)) {
                return true;
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(SLEEP_TIME);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

public boolean unLock(String key, String requestId) {
        return c8sClusterStringRedisClient.execute(LUA_SCRIPT_UNLOCK, Collections.singletonList(key), requestId) == 1L;
    }

Locking code should be no problem, several other parts of the system and other systems are used in this way, no problem, in addition, I tested this code in the test environment and found no problem, only the production environment has a problem, redis is cluster mode.
Why? There's nothing I can do.
I want to know what I should do next to troubleshoot this problem or has anyone encountered this problem?
